# Setting the focus on a element that was hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to trigger a focus event that occurs after an element is recognised as focusable within the DOM.

I'm showing form elements based on previous input. That works.
Then I want to set the focus for user input.

The following function fails to work unless I set a break point on the line with setTimeout.
I've tried using a function callback which also failed.

```
function triggerFocus(id,timeout){
    console.log('triggerFocus') ;
    console.log(id) ;
    /* the following works if a breakpoint is set*/
    setTimeout( function() { $( id ).focus() }, timeout ) ;
}

/* code used to show the elements from another function */
if ( $('#first').val() == '') {
    $('#firstRow').show() ;
    $('#middleRow').show() ;
    $('#lastRow').show() ;
    $('#emailRow').show() ;    
    triggerFocus($('#first'),100) ;    
} else {
    $('#docket').blur(docketBlur) ;
    $('#firstRow').show() ;
    $('#docketRow').show() ;
    triggerFocus($('#docket'),100) ;    
}
```

An example showing how to achieve this using a tab keyCode is at http://jsfiddle.net/pvrSU/
I discovered that the other element must be focusable before the blur event is fired.

Comment: How do you show the elements? add some code.

Comment: A semicolon missing after `$('#emailRow').show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function has a `complete` callback, you can use it in this case:

```
$('#emailRow').show(400, function(){
 .
 .
 .
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ar5wS/

Comment: Without a callback ... I'll try that. The callback function failed on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for that CD. I changed your jsfiddle example to execute on blur and the issue remains. It looks like the element has to be focusable before the blur event occurs.

Comment: Discovered that if the element is shown before the blur event it works. Thanks for your input @CD.. . It helped me discover a workaround.